# Javascript .disabled reversal?

Tags: javascript, function

[image: Program]

I am having trouble sending an invitation once I press "invite", when I press invite and there are no values present, it is disabled, and I write values once it is disabled, and the program is disabled an unable to perform the function.

Is there a way to reverse the .disabled command? Can I make a .enabled function?

Any advice would be helpful thank you!

```
  event.target.closest(".rsvp-categories").remove();
}

function validateRsvpInfo(event) {
  if (hogletName.value === "" || numberOfHoglets.value === "" || allergies.value === "") {
    inviteBtn.disabled = true;

  }


  else if (hogletName.value > 0 || numberOfHoglets.value > 0 || allergies.value > 0) {
    inviteBtn.disabled = false;
    addRsvpInfo();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's already in your script: `inviteBtn.disabled = false` o.O

Comment: I would not use `>` for testing string emptiness. eg `"test" > 0` is `false` so the `else if` statement could fail if all you are entering is non-numeric text.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For example, add an event handler to the inputs.  Let the handler determine button state based on field values. Try the onkeyup event.

Comment: Where are you calling this `validateRsvpInfo` function? You cannot call it from the `click` handler of the disabled button of course.